VBA Download data from multiple sharepoint excel files
Everyday i record information on a sharepoint excel file with the number of containers on each vehicle that arrives/departs at my depot. The same information is also recorded at other depots sites on sharepoint. I.e. if i load a vehicle with 10 containers i record 10 on my spreadsheet as the departing site and then the receiving depot also records 10 on their spreadsheet. There could be several other spreadsheets on sharepoint to pull this information from. I do have the links to each of the files.
As the files are all the sharepoint i was wondering if there was a way to just use the others sites information to complete my excel information.
**A bit about the spreadsheets. **

Each vehicle has a unique code that would be present in all spreadsheets (column D) - i guess this would be the search and search result term.
Each volume is on the same row as the unique code but in column L in all spreadsheets.
The worksheets are the same - e.g. both use "Mon", "Tue" etc

I can technically just open the other spreadsheets and copy the information manually but that is what i am trying to avoid as its time consuming and an very repeatable task.
First and foremost i just want to know if this is doable before i head off on an impossible task.
I little bit of guidance would be very welcomed to that i have a starting point.
I'm not a complete novice at VBA or formulas so if i get a starting point i can give it a go.
